# SpTBX: redraw issues on restore

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, sptbxlib

I see draw issues e.g. after making app window maximized and restored (on restoring window draws not ok).

drawn not ok (see empty areas):
[image: draw issue]

ok is:
[image: ok image]

I know i need to do `panel1.Invalidate` after restoring, i ll try it, but is it known "bug" in [SpTBX](http://www.silverpointdevelopment.com/sptbxlib/)? some "fix" possible?

Comment: What is 'not OK'? Do you mean texts are missing there? What Delphi version? Please update your question.

Comment: Ah, i updated the asking. added OK image. "white" spaces must be colored.

Comment: I don't think I've come across anything like it.